# Access - Database relationships and data collection form for a survey

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

Using MS Access, I would like to build a simple survey database with a data-collection form.

I need a unique survey, with, say, 15 questions. Each question has a unique answer from a choice of 3, each set of 3 options is unique to each question, so there are 45 options in total.

Each record in my survey should be linked to a single record in a table of respondents (i.e. the answers are those of a single respondent, whose personal data is stored in a table).

I understand that I'll need a table for the 15 questions, another for the 45 options, yet another for the respondents. But I don't know what middle tables I need, nor how to link them. And most importantly I don't know how to build the survey form in Access based on all this.

Comment: This is a design not programming issue and too broad for SO. At least will need a RespondentAnswers table. If there will be multiple surveys with varying questions, then also need Surveys and SurveyQuestions tables.

Comment: OK, thank you for your comment. Can you suggest another place where this kind of question belongs ?

Comment: There are lots of forums that focus on database, some particular to Access. Do a search on topic "Access database forums".